# Select from two tables and update a third one

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables :

```
tags: ( id, name, sefriendly )
articles_tags: ( id, tag_id, article_id )
articles: ( id, tags, ....)
```

I use the following sql to get the the tags for a specific article_id (here 10) which works fine by returning all tags names separated with comma

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( name ) AS art_tags
FROM tags, articles_tags
WHERE article_id =10
AND tags.id = tag_id
AND tags_group_id =0
GROUP BY article_id
```

I want to get all the tags for all ids in table articles and store theme in articles.tags

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want such a denormalization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below query with join condition

```
UPDATE articles
JOIN
  (
    SELECT 
      article_id, 
      GROUP_CONCAT( name ) AS art_tags
    FROM tags, articles_tags
    WHERE tags.id = tag_id
      AND tags_group_id =0
    GROUP BY article_id) tin
ON articles.id = tin.article_id
SET tags = tin.art_tags;
```

Comment: As expected. Thanks a lot.